# OpenFrameworks and Boost

Tags: c++, boost, openframeworks

In the last days I have been learning about the Boost and Open Frameworks. I did some programs using them, however when I use them in the same program g++ gives me the error

> undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

still I'm linking boost_system. Is there some reason to not use both libraries in the same program?

Answer (score 0):

That is a linker error, it needs an object file or library that provides the *definition* of function `boost::system::generic_category`.

Normally, to link to boost::system library add `-lboost_system` to the linker command line.

See [Link Your Program to a Boost Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) for more details.

Comment: I really did it. I have been doing programs with boost and OpenFrameworks separately, they compiled and everything was good. My problem is when I try to join them in the same program.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/danoli3/ofxOSXBoost) is the openFrameworks addon for Boost.

Download and see 'How to use' instructions.